# pam_sss System error, how to find the problem?

Tags: 16.04, pam

I was using Ubuntu 15.10, but upgraded to 16.04 LTS today. Since the upgrade I can no longer authenticate against our AD. I have tried using https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html as a guide to configure everything from scratch. All worked fine up till the step **Test Authentication**.

I cannot log in using

```
su - myusename
```

When I check my auth.log I see the following lines:

```
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: pam_krb5(su:auth): user myusename authenticated as myusename@DOMAIN
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: (rdconf1.c:744): path to luserconf set to /home/DOMAIN/myusername/.pam_mount.conf.xml
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: (pam_mount.c:365): pam_mount 2.14: entering auth stage
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: pam_sss(su:account): Access denied for user myusername: 4 (System error)
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: pam_acct_mgmt: System error
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: (pam_mount.c:133): clean system authtok=0x55da4f8329c0 (4)
Apr 28 12:59:30 PC1899 su[3134]: FAILED su for myusername by localuser
```

Googling for the error didn't bring up any leads that I could use.

How can I debug the problem? Or better, get it to work again?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look into /var/log/sssd/gpo_child.log (eventually raise log level beforehand). After the upgrade to 16.04 mine contained errors not being able to create
/var/lib/sss/gpo_cache/example.com

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/sss/gpo_cache/example.com
chown -R sssd:sssd /var/lib/sss/gpo_cache
```

resolved those and I could su and login using an AD user again.

Comment: This worked; I only had to created the /var/lib/sss/gpo_cached directory. The "example.com" portion was created automatically after that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your
`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` has

```
use_fully_qualified_domain_name = False
```

Also do the following

```
realm deny --all
realm permit --groups  <your_AD_Group@domain.com>
```

restart sssd and realm

Comment: Oi... I feel like a dunce. The realm commands worked like a charm. Much easier than trying to mess with config files like I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

With the excellent [pointer from Hmpf](https://askubuntu.com/a/777396/1060743) I checked the logs at `/var/log/sssd/` and realized in `gpo_child.log` that my machine was not able to fetch the GPOs, which are needed to determine who is authorized to login locally and/or remotely.

My local firewall did not allow outgoing traffic to port 445/tcp (SMB). After my machine was able to fetch the GPOs again, the login errors were gone.